# Latitude is to longitude as lateral is to

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Suppose we have a laser emitting a beam in the general direction of a target. Let P be the point nearest to the target, along the beam.

"Range" is a word commonly used for the distance to an object. I need terms to label two orthogonal components of this range from the perspective of the laser: the component along the beam (i.e. from the laser source to P), and the component orthogonal to the beam (i.e. from P to the target). My preferred terms would have been "longeral range" and "lateral range" if only "longeral" existed.

An sample sentence would be (in the voice of the laser) "The longeral range of object X is ten meters." This would mean the range of P (from the laser) is ten meters.

Comment: I feel like this should be some thing along the lines of *displacement* or *error* or *correction*, because it's fundamentally describing how *wrong* the aiming is. Having said that, maybe *lateral* (side-to-side) vs ***vertical*** (up-and-down)? I think we can help you find a more precise term if you describe in more detail *why* the laser is pointed at "some point P near the target" rather than directly "at the target". Do you not have line of sight? Then you might prefer ballistics to a laser...

Comment: Several websites (both dictionaries and sites like Yahoo Answers) point to the antonym of lateral being **medial**, though I'm admittedly not 100% sure that's the axis you're after here..

Comment: @DanBron What I am after is neither side-to-side nor up-and-down but this-side-to-other-side.

Comment: @DanBron do you mean front-to-back (or back-to-front)?

Comment: @Michael I don't understand the question you asked me.

Comment: @DanBron by 'this-side-to-other-side' do you mean anterior and posterior? As in, a movement in the Z-axis.

Comment: @Michael That distinction is deliberately unspecified by the idiom "side to side". Asking that is like asking "when you said 'a few', did you mean 4 or 7?". But in this particular context, it probably makes most sense to interpret it as orthogonal both to the axis created by the directed beam of light (from the laser source to the point P) as well as orthogonal to the axis created by the force of gravity (i.e. the vertical axis).

Comment: @DanBron just realised I've been @ ing the wrong person. I meant to clarify Museful's comment that I immediately followed.

Comment: To me "lateral" and "longitudinal" imply a contrasting, third "vertical" dimension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be [longitudinal](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/longitudinal):

> **Adjective**
>
> **longitudinal** ‎(*not comparable*)
>
> 1. Relating to length, or to longitude.
> 2. Running in the direction of the long axis of a body.

(Wiktionary)

Comment: Would you then also say "latitudinal range" rather than "lateral range"?

Comment: No. "Lateral" is the adjective form of "latitude", but the adjective form of "longitude" is "longitudinal". Verb/adjective/noun forms of different words were (and continue to be) developed at different historical points along the evolution of the language, so presuming words which are used in similar contexts should use the same suffixes in those forms is a false assumption.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. Linking just a website is not encouraged in this community as your link can become invalid if the linked page changes. Please include essential parts of the link in your post and make sure that you take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.